Can't get this sort function to work in Python
I have been writing a function to sort and pick out specific words to form a sentence. The problem is I cannot for the life of me get any form of .sort or sorted to work. I need the items on the list to be sorted in numerical order, and have the words to the right of the integers stay with their partnered integer.
This is my code:
def decode(message_file):

    decoded_message = []

#opens the external file, and places it into file, and then reads file into message
    with open(message_file, 'r') as file:
        message = file.read()

#takes the message and splits it between the numbers and the txt
    pairs = message.split()

    #sorted(pairs, key = lambda x: x[0])
    pairs.sort(key = lambda x: [0])

    print(pairs)

decode("test.txt")

The pairs.sort and sorted towards the bottom are where I am having issue. No matter what I do, it does not actually sort the list, and it always prints the same.
test.txt:
3 love
6 computers
2 dogs
4 cats
1 I
5 you

Output:
['3', 'love', '6', 'computers', '2', 'dogs', '4', 'cats', '1', 'I', '5', 'you']

I have tried different .sort and sorted functions, and messed around with the different syntax of writing keys and trying to figure out how to actually get things to move. I am pretty new to Python so I don't know if I'm just missing something.
My Output Should Be:
['1', 'I', '2', 'dogs', '3', 'love', '4', '5', 'you', 'cats', '6', 'computers']


One little hint, using [0] as the key isn't going to be useful.  That's not indexing into a tuple, it's just creating a list with a single constant value.

If you're sorting a list like ['3', 'love', '6', 'computers'] then obviously it's going to put those in order like ['3', '6', 'computers', 'love'] and it is correct to do so.
What you want is to sort the lines, not each separate word. You could split("\n") but python makes it easy to read a file line by line by just iterating over the file. You do have to remove the newlines, though.
def decode(message_file):
    # read line by line
    decoded_message = []
    with open(message_file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            decoded_message.append(line.strip())

    # split each line into pairs so you can look at the first word of each
    pairs = [line.split() for line in decoded_message]
    
    # now sort the lines
    # you had x[0] in the comments, but typoed it as [0]
    # also you need to convert to int because if they are strings then "10" < "9" 
    pairs.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
    
    # and here I'm just making it pretty,
    # so it looks like the output format you want
    result = []
    for pair in pairs:
        result.extend(pair)
    return result

result = decode("data/test.txt")
print(result)

You do want your function to return a value, so you can write tests. If you want to print it, you just print it.

itertools makes some of that easier, but I decided to try to keep the original code as unchanged as possible, and try not to introduce new stuff.

Thank you so much. I can see what I was doing wrong now. I was looking at, well basically everything wrong, but I really didn't understand what I was doing with the lists. It all makes sense now.

You can read all lines to a list, then sort the lines according the first integer and as a last step flatten the list with sorted lines:
with open("test.txt", "r") as f_in:
    lines = [i for i in map(str.strip, f_in) if i]

out = [
    word
    for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
    for word in line.split()
]

print(out)

Prints:
['1', 'I', '2', 'dogs', '3', 'love', '4', 'cats', '5', 'you', '6', 'computers']


Nice touch checking for empty lines.

If the keys for sorting are the first digits in the line then your expected output should be
['1', 'I', '2', 'dogs', '3', 'love', '4', 'cats', '5', 'you', '6', 'computers']
This can be attained by splitting the lines without separating the keys from the words then sort them and split again to get your expected format.
text = """
3 love
6 computers
2 dogs
4 cats
1 I
5 you
"""
text = text.strip()
message = text.split('\n')
message.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
ans = []
for string in message: # splitting each of the keys from its words
    temp = string.split(" ")
    ans.extend(temp)
print(ans)


The key for sorting is first integer part of each line.
text = """
3 love
6 computers
2 dogs
4 cats
1 I
5 you""".strip()

new_text = '\n'.join(
    sorted(
        text.splitlines(),
        key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]),
    )
)

print(new_text)
result = new_text.split()
print(result)

1 I
2 dogs
3 love
4 cats
5 you
6 computers
['1', 'I', '2', 'dogs', '3', 'love', '4', 'cats', '5', 'you', '6', 'computers']

